# How does rep calc work when nearing the 200 daily rep cap?

Tags: support, bug

My rep cap doesn't *appear* to have been breached, yet I'm not seeing upvotes increase my rep in the past 15 minutes or so.

[image]

Also, I've used https://dba.stackexchange.com/reputation to check my rep; it states I *have* reached 200 rep today.

```
-- 2017-08-30 rep +260  = 36789     
 3    184756 (-2)
 2    184622 (10)
 3    184756 (-2)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184756 (5)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2     40062 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184806 (10)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184806 (10)
 2    184622 (10)
 2    184806 (10)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184805 (5)
 2    184806 [4]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184806 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184793 [0]
 2    184622 [0]
 2    184806 [0]
 2    184805 [0]
 2    184832 [0]
 2    184832 [0]
-- 2017-08-31 rep +200  = 36989     

** rep today: 200
** rep this week (2017-08-27 - 2017-09-02): 755
** rep this month (2017-08-01 - 2017-08-31): 2395
** rep this quarter (2017-07-01 - 2017-09-30): 2917
** rep this year (2017-01-01 - 2017-12-31): 9280
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 36989 :)
```

Is this just another "blame it on caching" thing?

How long can caching be the problem?  This is an hour later:

[image]

FYI, I'm tracking my progress towards the Epic badge and the counter did not register a +200 day yesterday, even though I had enough upvotes for a +400 point day.

Just an update, this issue is *still* not fixed, even though I now have 21 +200 days:

```
-- 2018-03-02 rep +209  = 40679     

** rep today: 209
** rep this week (2018-02-25 - 2018-03-03): 354
** rep this month (2018-03-01 - 2018-03-31): 304
** rep this quarter (2018-01-01 - 2018-03-31): 1779
** rep this year (2018-01-01 - 2018-12-31): 1779
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 40679 :)

days represented 1366
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 16 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 21 days
earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits
```

[image]

Comment: @oded - this clearly *is* a bug, even if it is only a *display* bug.

Comment: @oded - how long does [eventual consistency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352454/it-is-possible-to-gain-rep-past-your-rep-cap-through-a-bug-loophole#comment493995_352454) take?  My progress towards Epic still has not recognized that 200-rep day.

Comment: Aparently, there is no such thing as eventual consistency when it comes to +200 rep days with an un-upvote.

Comment: This fairly recent developer comment https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266447/progress-bar-for-epic-badge#comment864550_266447 suggests the progress bar is incorrect, and you are actually at 18/50. Either way, you haven't actually earned Epic yet, so the point is somewhat moot.

Comment: ouch.  https://twitter.com/aalear/status/903382914750177282

Answer (score 6):

This comes down to a display oddity that occurs when there is an unupvote that takes place.

The unupvote shows that is happened today because that's when the event took place, but the vote and reputation are removed from whatever day it originally took place. So if you add all your events from today, excluding the -5 you'll get 200 rep for the day, which is the correct number.

This is [also explained over on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308548/426671), but blame the unupvote for making the rep display strange for the day.

Comment: I'm going to unupvote this later.  ;-)

Comment: If only meta votes counted for rep. :P

Comment: FYI, my progress towards Epic is still not fixed.  Says 17/50, but [/reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/reputation) says 18 days at 200 or better.

Comment: @MaxVernon We don't actively maintain the /reputation page, so I wouldn't suggest checking there for your progress towards rep caps, etc. We know that reputation appears different in both places, unfortunately [reputation is difficult](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/905542844156436481) and they will be looking at fixing the display in multiple places in the future. Right now, if you're tracking your badge progress what is shown on the user reputation tab is what's being used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Prior to Sept. 1st, I had 17/50 - on Sept. 1st, I had a day with *way* over 200 rep, which should make it 18 days towards the 50 required for the Epic badge.  I'm only looking at the /reputation page for convenience.

Comment: just tying the two posts together with this link to [my meta.se question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301720/do-i-have-17-50-200-rep-days-or-do-i-have-18)